# How to run JS function on button click, using PHP form data?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have got a form on my WordPress homepage that takes one input.

```
<form method='post' action='<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/test123/' >
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" required="required">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

When submitted it redirects and passes the input to the `test123` page (the page has a custom php template). If I add `Hello <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>` then it works without issue.

However, I have a JavaScript function that should run after the submit button is clicked. The users input `name` needs to be used inside the function.

My first thought was to use `onclick="test();"` but I don't believe that will work for calling the function on a different page, and I still have the issue of passing the PHP data into the JS function.

I've tried using `<script type="text/javascript> .... </script>` in `test123` page's php template file with no luck.

Edit:

```
<?php /* Template Name: test123 */ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

Your email is <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>

<script type="text/javascript>
    function testing() {
        console.log(<?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>)
    }

    testing();
</script>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear because you say "after the submit button is clicked" and "I don't believe that will work for calling the function on a different page". Are you asking how to run the function after the submit button has been clicked but before the form submits or are you asking how to run the function *on the next page* when that page loads?

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear. I'm asking how I run the function on the next page when it loads.

Comment: *I've tried using `<script type="text/javascript> .... </script>`* — That is the correct approach. We can't tell why it doesn't work without a [mcve]. Make sure you check the developer tools in your browser, in particular the Console tab which will display JS error messages.

Comment: @Quentin Please check the edit for the entire PHP code. On submitting the form, the above code correctly produces a `Your email is example@example.com`, but doesn't console log anything (doesn't produce any errors either).

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript

Comment: `console.log(example@example.com);` should give you [SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token](http://jsbin.com/yiwibod/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: Oh. `<script type="text/javascript>` — You have a typo causing an HTML error. Use [a validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/). That's why the JS doesn't error. It never runs.

Comment: You're right, now it's giving me an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: X is not defined` (X being the user input)

Comment: — Because it is a variable, not a string literal. Still a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript

Comment: It's working, thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

If you using jQuery in Wordpress

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
 var name = $(this).find('input[name=name]').val();
 // do smth with name
 return true;
});
```

Comment: Lol, why dislike?

Comment: I didn't like / dislike (I have less than 15 rep, so I can't apparently). So I could include that jQuery in a script tag in my WordPress page or in the PHP template file?

Comment: This will run the function on the current page before the form submits. The OP is asking how to run the function on the next page.

Comment: jQuery by default already included in Wordpress themes. If you did not turn it off it might work.
If `$` is not working, try to replace all `$` to `jQuery`, like `jQuery('form'). ...`